# Определить путь к сайту на localhost

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, isp

На сервере под CentOS и Isp Panel (nginx) понадобилось обратится к размещенному на нем сайту через localhost. Но я не могу найти карту роутинга localhost и нужный урл. Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: Добрый день! если под картой роутинга вы понимаете конфигурацию вашего веб сервера, то обычно ispmanager кладет основной конфиг nginx по пути /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. А уже в нем будут инклуды, которые подключают дополнительные конфигурации веб сайтов на сервере, например include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; в conf.d лежат обычно конфиги с локайшенами общими для всех вебсайтов в примеру phpadmin или afterlogic, а в sites-enabled сами конфиги веб-сайтов. Если же карта роутинга это соответствие ip-host то обычно файлик лежит в /etc/hosts

Comment: Сначала двигаться в сторону уточнения смысла вопроса. Что такое обратиться к размещённому сайту? Вы хотите с самого сервера через wget сделать запрос, из браузера или что? Непонятно, что вы считаете "картой роутинга", нет такого термина, тем более применительно к localhost: трафик к локалхосту не маршрутизируется, не передаётся через шлюз по умолчанию -- ну таково уже само определение локалхоста. На localhost'е могут быть размещены несколько сайтов, вы сами-то знаете, какой из них вам нужен?

Comment: @AK сайтов может быть и много, но через localhost URI можно получить доступ только к одному по очевидным обстоятельствам.